# NSUserDefaults saving JSON data from AFNetworking request, available in initial viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to store some json data in an NSUserDefaults dictionary by using AFHttpNetworking library in AppDelegate.

My problem is that before the request completes in AppDelegate, the initial view controller is loaded and the  NSDictionary *settings = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"mysettings"]; is nil. After the ViewController loads, the NSUserDefaults is written successfully (in the next launch the data is there) but I cannot access the data in the initial run.

How can I ensure that the json object is saved in the nsuserdefaults before the viewcontroller asks for it's data?

Comment: Why are you saving the data in `NSUserDefaults` just to pass it to the view controller?

Comment: I am using this data in many locations of the app successfully, but the only case I cannot access it is the initial view controller because I think the data is not there when requested.

Comment: My point is that `NSUserDefaults` is not really the properly place to store data just as a convenience to use the data throughout the app. `NSUserDefaults` is meant to persist little bits of flags and settings so they can be reloaded the next time the app is started.

Comment: hm, then maybe is my mistake trying to use it that way, maybe I should use a global variable for that reason...

Comment: @Shardon if you want to access data in many location than use Appdelegate variable snd store data in this variable so you can access in any class

Comment: My actual problem is that I get the data I need in AppDelegate from a network request in a JSON object, but the data is not yet available when the initial controller is rendered. I don't want to make a synchronous call for obvious reasons, so how do I get the data to use them if I need to make the request in AppDelegate?